# Remote Desktop execution of a report in a desktop .NET application

Tags: .net, reporting-services, remote-desktop, timeoutexception

When I use remote desktop execution mode of my desktop application which uses SSRS reporting, if the user has not logged to server yet, this error appears in application running the reoprt:

> ASP.NET session has expired
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.AspNetSessionExpiredException: ASP.NET session has expired
>
> Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace: [AspNetSessionExpiredException: ASP.NET session has expired]
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor() +722
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler(String operationType) +687
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +57
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

If the user logs on server by "Remote Desktop Connection", errors disappears for that user.

Anyone has any idea why this error may be raised?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing the settings of IIS for my webapp. If you encounter such problem, you need to go to IIS settings on your server (Administrative tools). Then right click on your website under "Default Website". Click properties and go to ASP.net tab. After that click on "Change configuration..." button. A form appears in which there is a tab named "Authentication". Click it and change the "Authentication Mode" to "None". This will solve access prevention in RDP when windows authentication mode.

Regards